# Proving that $|\operatorname{Aut}(C_n)|=2n$.

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, permutations, automorphism-group, algebraic-graph-theory

> Question: Prove that $|\operatorname{Aut}(C_n)|=2n$.

This the question $2$ chapter $2$, in the book *Algebraic Graph Theory*, Godsil and Royle.

I've managed to prove that $\left|\operatorname{Aut}(C_n)\right|\geq2n$ considering that the subgroup generated by the permutation $(12\ldots n)$ and the reflexion.

I haven't been able to prove equality.

Comment: orbit-stabilizer theorem

Answer (score 4):

Let $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ be the vertices of $C_n$, with edges $v_i v_{i+1}$ for $i=1, \dots, n-1$ as well as $v_1 v_n$.

To pick an automorphism of $C_n$, we need to:

1. Pick $k \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and decide that $v_1 \mapsto v_k$. Of course, one of these possibilities has to be true, and there's $n$ of them.
2. Because $v_1 v_2$ has to map to another edge, we know that $v_2 \mapsto v_{k-1}$ or $v_2 \mapsto v_{k+1}$. Choose one of these options, and already you have $2n$ possibilities.

So now it remains to show that each of these choices can be completed to only one automorphism of $C_n$. (You've already shown that each choice can be completed to at least one automorphism.) To do this, check that there's only one possibility for $v_3$, and then that leaves only one possibility for $v_4$, and so on by induction until you get to $v_n$.

(Note that *in general* this strategy also requires us to check that at the end, what we've defined really is an automorphism. We can skip that here, because you've already proved that at least $2n$ automorphisms exist, and here we see that there are at most $2n$.)